# SQL - Optimizing complex paged search querys

Tags: sql, database, optimization, stored-procedures, paging

I'm currently developing a stored procedure for a complex search in a big database. Because there are many thousand entries, that could be returned I want to use paging. Although it is working, I think it's too slow. I read a lot of posts and articles regarding pagination of SQL queries and optimizing performance. But most 'optimizations' were only helpful for very basic requests like 'give items 20-30 from table x'.

Since our world is not that simple and there are more complex queries to make I would like to get some help optimizing the following query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SearchItems]
@SAttr1 BIT = 0,
@SAttr2 BIT = 0,
@SAttr3 BIT = 0,
@Flag1 BIT = 0,
@Flag2 BIT = 0,
@Param1 VARCHAR(20),
@Param2 VARCHAR(10),
@SkipCount BIGINT,
@TakeCount BIGINT,
@SearchStrings NVARCHAR(1000)    
AS
    DECLARE @SearchStringsT TABLE(
        Val NVARCHAR(30)
    )

    INSERT INTO @SearchStringsT 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@SearchStrings,',');

WITH ResultTable AS (
    SELECT  Table1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Table1.ID ASC) AS [!ROWNUM!]
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.FK1
    INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.ID = Table3.FK2
    INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table3.XX = Table4.FKX
    WHERE Table1.X1 = @Parameter1
    AND
        (@Flag1 = 0 OR Table1.X2 = 1) AND
        (@Flag2 = 0 OR Table2.X4 = @Parameter2) AND
        (@Flag3 = 0 OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table5 WHERE Table5.ID = Table3.X1)) 
    AND
    (                   
        (@SAttr1 = 0 OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @SearchStringsT WHERE Table1.X1 LIKE Val)) OR
        (@SAttr2 = 0 OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @SearchStringsT WHERE Table2.X1 LIKE Val)) OR
        (@SAttr3 = 0 OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @SearchStringsT WHERE Table3.X1 LIKE Val)) OR
        (@SAttr4 = 0 OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @SearchStringsT WHERE Table4.X1 LIKE Val))
    )
)
SELECT TOP(@TakeCount) * FROM ResultTable
WHERE [!ROWNUM!] BETWEEN (@SkipCount + 1) AND (@SkipCount + @TakeCount)
RETURN
```

The @SAttr parameters are bit parameters to specify whether to search a field or not , the @Flag parameters are turning on/off checking of some boolean expressions, @SkipCount and @TakeCount are used for paging. @SearchString is a comma separated list of search keywords, already including the wild cards.

I hope someone can help me optimizing this, because a single search in a database with 20.000 entries in the main table lasts 800ms and its increasing with entry count. The final application needs to deal with over 100.000 entries.

I thank you very much for every help.
Marks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with Tom H. that this may be a case where dynamic SQL is best (and I'm a stored proc kinds girl, so I don't say that very often), it may be that you don't have good indexing on your tables. Are all the possible search fields indexed? Are all the FKs indexed?

I mean 20,000 is a tiny, tiny table and 100,000 is too, so it really seems as if you might not have indexed yet.

Check your execution plan to see if indexes are being used.

Comment: You are right. I have almost no indexes right now, but thats because of the fact that I will have more insert operations than read operations. And since indexing slows down inserts, i think i will get no overall performance benefit from using indexes. But i have to do some profiling on that.

Comment: Now I have indexed all primary keys as clustered (for the joins) and all FKs, 'order by' or 'where' columns as unclustered indexes. There is no significant change in speed of the query. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures are not very good at being super-generic because it prevents SQL Server from always using optimal methods. In a similar situation recently I used (*gasp*) dynamic SQL. My search stored procedures would build the SQL code to perform the search, using pagination just like you have it (WITH with a ROW_NUMBER(), etc.). The advantage was that if parameters indicated that one piece of information wasn't being used in the search then the generated code would omit it. In the end it allowed for better query plans.

Make sure that you use sp_executesql properly to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: and make sure to read this first
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Agree with you this particular task may be better done in dynamic SQl.

Comment: @HLGEM - Thanks, I started to look for that link to post it here and then got distracted by a shiny object :)

Comment: The main reason for me, using stored procedures are the user rights management and therefore security benefits. And don't you think some '@Flag = 0 OR' are done faster then sending such a big query to the DB every time a search is performed?

Comment: Sending a query to the database takes almost no resources. It's a few bytes over the network. Of course, that's not how I did it anyway though. I called a stored procedure exactly as you are, but in the stored procedure I built up the exact SQL to run. Using the @Flag = 0 OR logic doesn't work, because SQL Server can't account for that condition ahead of time - it still creates a query plan as if the second condition might have to be checked, which usually results in table scans.

Comment: @Tom H. - Thanks for the info on the query plan. Is there no possibility, to turn on/off the check of a field?

Comment: Read through Erland's page on dynamic SQL above and also importantly the page on search procedures linked within it somewhere. He talks about the possibility of using WITH RECOMPILE and why that doesn't work so well.